# JS parseFloat creates Int when parsing ASP.NET MVC model data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parsefloat

I want to parse Model data as a float to Javascript variable, but I will always get no decimals

```
function initMap() {
            var latitude = parseFloat("@Model.latitude");
            var longitude = parseFloat("@Model.longitude");

            console.log(latitude + " " + longitude);
        }
```

For example, if `Model.latitude = 46.3245` I will get `46`.

I have also tried this: `var latitude = parseFloat("@Model.latitude").toFixed(4);` but I get `46.0000`

What can I do ?

Comment: Once check what is value coming in Model.latitude and Model.longitude

Comment: They are both floats, but I get them as  strings to use them in js variables.

Comment: syntax seems pretty fine.

Comment: Check that the returned decimal values don't have a comma in place of a decimal point because `parseFloat(46,3245)` would return `46` (ignoring everythin after the comma).

Comment: Yes, this worked. I replaced the comma with a dot in the strng before parsing it and it worked. Thanks mate